# I don't understand how to vendor jQuery in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Why won't jQuery work when I try to vendor it. I know how to add jQuery using Google's CDN, but I want to be able to vendor it.

I have a path in my rails app that is "public/vendor/jquery.js" which is where my tutorial says to copy and paste the jQuery uncompressed file from the website. Next, on my `application.html.erb`  I have this.

```
<head>
  <title>AjaxDemo</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' =>   
    true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script src="/public/vendor/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/public/javascripts/rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Lastly, in my `public/javascripts/ratings.js` file I have this which is suppose to indicate to me that it was loaded.

```
$(function(){
  console.log("loaded...");
});
```

When I check my console, the files have a 404 error. Why is that? Why is my jQuery code suppose to go in public/vendor and not in the assets? Can someone please help me make sense of this? I've read in Agile Web Development that third party code should be in the vendor file, but shouldn't the jQuery code be in the assets?

-----Edit------------

I've confused myself even more with jQuery. I could really really use some clarification on what goes where. I just watched a railsCasts episode #136 talking about jQuery and in the video it says to add this code in the application.html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery', 'application' %>
```

Adding that line of code gives me an error in my rails app.

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetFilteredError in Meetings#index
```

However, it's come to my attention that I already have jQuery installed in my rails app due to the jquery-rails gem. I have a jquery.js file within

```
app/assets/javascripts/jquery.js
```

Do I need to add a script src in my application or not? Like I said, some clear and concise clarification would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just a small hint, Railscast #136 is very old, almost 6 years. A LOT has changed in Rails since then. The easiest way to see 'what goes where' is just to actually create a new rails app with the latest release and take look at the code generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating a new Rails app, you already have jQuery working.

Otherwise, you can just add:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

to your `Gemfile` and then run `bundle install`.

After that, open your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file and include:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Now you're able to use jQuery.

For more information: https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails#installation

Comment: Hey Lucas, thanks for the reply. It turns out I already did have jquery-rails in my gemfile to begin with. So are you saying I'm able to create a jquery.js file in my assets/javascripts directory and use jQuery code just like that? Is my tutorial wrong? Why would I ever need to vendor for a rails app then?

Comment: Hey @DanRubio, it won't generate a `jquery.js` file. The JS file will always be inside the gem. But after add the gem and after include the `//= require jquery` to your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file, you'll be able to execute jQuery code.